# SSIS: Inserting int32, string variable values into SQL table

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package which has a Execute SQL task, where I am using the following statement which is not working. Could you please explain me why?

```
INSERT INTO SSIS.FIIN_FilesInfo
    (FIIN_PKIN_package_id, FIIN_package_connection_string, FIIN_created_date)
SELECT '" +  @[User::package_id]] + "' AS Expr1, '" + @[User::package_connection_string]+ "' AS Expr2, GETDATE() AS Expr3
```

Here, 
`FIIN_PKIN_package_id is int32 data type`
`FIIN_package_connection_string is string data type`

It works if I insert only string values using the variable mapping. But it does not work if I try to insert int32 and string value then using variable mapping it does not. That is why I am trying this way. Many thanks in advance.

Note: With variable mapping I was using this query:

```
INSERT INTO SSIS.FIIN_FilesInfo
    (FIIN_PKIN_package_id, FIIN_package_connection_string, FIIN_created_date)
VALUES (?,?, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the `int32` variable to a string.

In SSIS you can just put the type (enclosed in parenthesis) to which you want to convert the variable before the variable; in case of string you also have to specify the maximum number of chars.

If your `int32` is `@[User::package_id]` then use `(DT_WSTR, 10)@[User::package_id]`; remember to adjust number 10 to the maximum expected number of chars.